# Bounding the expected number of samples to select items with different probabilities and combinatorial constraints

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, optimization, stochastic-processes

We have a set $S$ of $n$ items $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n$ that we select and remove (i.e., without replacement) from $S$ in a sequential fashion. The probability to select each of them at the beginning of the process is known and respectively equal to $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$, where for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ there exists a positive integer $n_{j}$ such that $p_j=\frac{n_{j}}{n}$. Without loss of generality, assume $p_1\ge p_2\ge \ldots \ge p_n$. Let $S_t$ be the set of items at trial $t$, i.e., after having selected (and removed) $t-1$ items. The probability to select each item $i_j\in S_t$ at trial $t$ is equal to $\frac{p_j}{\sum_{k\in S_t} p_k}$.

---

**Question(s):** Let $K_j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be the unique trial where $i_j$ is selected. Let $M_j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be the *first* trial where $i_1, i_2,\ldots, i_j$ are *all* selected. Can we prove or disprove that there are two positive constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (independent of $n$ and the given probabilities $p_k$ for $1\le k\le n$) such that $\mathbb{E}[K_j]$ and $\mathbb{E}[M_j]$ are lower bounded by $\frac{\alpha}{p_j}$ and upper bounded by $\frac{\beta}{p_j}$?

---

---

***Note:*** *This question originated from a discussion (for a general version of this problem) in [Probabilistic problem on sampling items without replacement with different probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4580592/509383) .*

Comment: if you want more arbitrary distributions, which are still rational, you may want to define number of items as $N$ and the parameter $n$ separately.

Comment: Exactly @kodlu . I formulated the problem in a naive way, but I already received the answer. Hence, I will write soon a new problem more general in this sense.

Comment: This does sound interesting, too. But as made clear here, we necessarily have $N\ge n$, so $N$ must depend on $n$. Then, I'm pretty sure that also $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend on the specific choice of the sequence $(N(n))_n$, and there will be some upper bound for $N$ above which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do not exist, my guess is that it has to be linear in $n$. Otherwise, as explained in the answer to the related question, $1/p_j=N(n)=\omega(n)$ is possible.

Comment: Thank you @Matija . In this problem I just forgot to add $2$ in the denominator of the $p_j$ definition, which should have been $p_j=\frac{n_j}{2n}$ instead of $p_j=\frac{n_j}{n}$. You can see my updated problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4585563/509383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under these assumptions you necessarily have $p_j=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $j$ because $1=\sum_jp_j\ge\sum_j\frac{1}{n}=1$ with equality if and only if $p_j=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $j$. Hence, this experiment corresponds to the choice of a uniform permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
As discussed for the other question, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[K_j]&=\frac{1}{n}+(n-1)\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}2+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}3+\dots+\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n-i}{n-i+1}\cdot n\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n-1}{2}=\frac{n-1}{2n}\frac{1}{p_j}, 
\end{align*}
so the answer is yes if we restrict to $n\ge 2$, in which case $\alpha=\frac{1}{4}$ suffices, and $\beta=1$. These bounds also hold for $\mathbb E[M_j]$ because $\frac{\alpha}{p_j}\le\mathbb E[K_j]\le\mathbb E[M_j]\le n=\frac{\beta}{p_j}$.